Doxygen static constexpr in namespace not displayed
I want to use Doxygen to add static constexpr defined in namespaces to my documentation.
This does not seem to work. Only constexpr that are not static are transferred.
I'm using Doxygen 1.12.0
Does anyone have an idea?
This is my example code:
/// @file foo.cpp

/** @defgroup group_1
*/
/** @defgroup group_2
 *  @ingroup group_1
*/

class ABC {
public:
/// @ingroup group_2
/// @brief lorem
static constexpr uint32_t AA=123;
/// @ingroup group_2
/// @brief ipsum
static constexpr uint32_t BB=456;

private:
/// @ingroup group_2
/// @brief what_abcd
static constexpr uint32_t  private_abcdef = 42;
};

namespace parameterXYZ {
/// @ingroup group_2
/// @brief lorem
constexpr uint32_t D=77;
/// @ingroup group_2
/// @brief lorem
static constexpr uint32_t E=88;
}

int main() {

    /// @ingroup group_2
    /** \code */
    printf("ABC");
    /** \endcode */

    return 0;
}

And this is the result:

I try to enable/disable all relevant Doxygen build parameters and also try to modify my code. Nothing helped.

You need to include EXTRACT_STATIC = YES into your doxyfile. I presume this is what you wanted right?


could also check EXTRACT_ALL = YES (optional)

Yes, this works perfect. Thanks @Constantinos-Glynos
